# Where to find statistics about the WW2 German bombings of Britain, regarding German bomber sorties versus British civilian casulties?

Tags: world-war-two, statistics

I'm interested in a comparison of early versus later stages of attacks during the German bombing campaign against the UK. I've searched through many sources, but they usually give totals over the entire Battle of Britain, or the entire Blitz, but not broken to months.
The sources I've found, which are broken tom months, document generic events but not statistics.

I would *assume*, that the very first air raids against a Birtish city caused more damage than later ones, if we calibrate them by the tonnage of bombs in the attacking aircraft: the first bombings might have been a surprise, but later the British developed more and more defenses to reduce the damage: bombing shelters, warning sirens, more and more interceptors engaging the attackers, radar, etc., and generally better experience for mitigating the damage.

Is there a freely available source where I can find something like this?

- august 1940, x1 German sorties started, y1 ground casualties caused
- october 1940, x2 German sorties started, y2 ground casualties caused

If it's a weekly or daily breakup, it would be OK as well.

Comment: My understanding is that the primary objective of the campaign changed halfway through from taking out Britain's anti-air capacity to punishing civilians in the major cities. There's likely to be a big difference in your data at that point which won't be easily explainable by any other theory you try to apply to it.